# Java 7 - Stream data through class hierarchy

Tags: java, performance, io, stream

I am trying to write some sort of class hierarchy, more specifically, an execution hierarchy. Data should be passed down the hierarchy through each element whilst being modified during the process. Concurrency is not an issue, although it is part of a multithreaded program. **To clarify:** I do *not* want to have a hierarchy of classes, I want a hierarchy of instances. Something like this:

```
public abstract class ExecutionElement extends OutputStream {
    private ExecutionElement child;
    private InputStream input;

    public ExecutionElement(InputStream input) {
        this.input = input;
    }

    public ExecutionElement(ExecutionElement parent) {
        parent.addChild(this);
    }

    private void addChild(ExecutionElement child) {
        this.child = child;
    }

    protected PipedOutputStream processData() {
        // process the data according to the purpose of the current element. 
        // pseudocode from here
        // this is the root element, read from the InputStream and write to child element 
    }

    protected PipedOutputStream processData(PipedOutputStream data) {
        // this is an intermediary element, read from PipedOutputStream -->
        // convert the stream to pipedInputStream
        // process data
        // write to child
    }
}
```

**The idea** is the following: I pass some sort of `InputStream` to the root element of the hierarchy. This data is then modified by the root element (either inserting or removing specific parts of the stream) and then passed to the child element. Rinse and repeat.

This whole process has to be as performant as possible. Of course there will be several different implementations of the `ExecutionElement` with different purposes. Lately I've been thinking about using `PipedInputStream` and `PipedOutputStream` in order to speed things up, but it does not work for me yet. Furthermore, I cannot use external libraries for several reasons. We are using Java 7 for the project, so we cannot use [Streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) as suggested, since this is a Java 8 feature.

**The question** is: Do you have any suggestions / recommendations regarding the design of the hierarchy? Any specific design principles I should follow?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? Maybe you can use *Decorator*s.

Comment: Maybe you can use streams: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html

Comment: @AdamArold Well, frankly it is. But does it really matter? I do not quite get how Decorators should help in this matter. Could you elaborate a bit? Yes, I do want subclass-specific behaviour, but that will not solve the overall design problem, will it?

Comment: @Armand I forgot to mention, that we use Java 7 for the project. I will add it in the description. But thanks for the tip ;)

Comment: If you need to process data using classes in a hierarchy then you can create Decorators (which are basically wrappers) and make them implement the same interface (class hierarchy) and wrap them on each other. From my experience if you have a hierarchy which has more than 3 levels (interface included) it means that you are doing it wrong.

Comment: @AdamArold OK, maybe I should clarify a few bits first. Please see the edited question again (in a few minutes).

Comment: What you really want is a pipeline which is also a `LinkedList` in your case.  This has nothing to do with hierarchies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You essentially want to implement the `Pipeline Pattern`.

If you're passing byte data, you've got a ready made implementation with the `InputStream/OutputStream` classes (where you'd extend `FilterInputStream` and `FilterOutputStream`). If you intend to pass objects, I recommend creating your own "object stream" classes (don't use `ObjectInputStream/ObjectOutputStream`, they're for serialization).

Comment: That is exactly what I am looking for! Since I cannot use external libraries, I might implement something like that on my own. Thank you for pointing me to this! :)